# MVC ValidationMessageFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to show a image instead of text when validation fails but ValidationMessageFor encodes my 'validationMessage'.
I'm trying to specify a validationMessage using a plain img tag declaration
How can i do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create your own HTMLHelper.

Something like:

```
 public static MvcHtmlString   ValidationImage(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {

        if (!htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
                  //todo: strip out the information you need from the model and  return <img/> tag(s).    
        }

        return null;

    }
```

Comment: This validates whole model. I want to validate a single field

Answer (score 0):

you can declare a const string containing image formatted in html like:

```
const string ERROR_IMAGE = "<img src=\"...\"  alt=\"\" />";
```

in the View Action you can do something like this:

```
if(Something is Ine error)
   ModelState.AddModelError(Something, ERROR_IMAGE);
```